# RestKit merging context function is nil'ing properties

Tags: ios, save, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So I create an object

```
MyObject *object = [mainManagedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject"];

SomeOtherObject *someOtherObject = [s_mainManagedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject"];

// in case you're wondering the inverse relationship of someOtherObject's relation ship to myObject is one to many
// so this should remove the idea that setting someOtherObjects.relationship to something else was causing the property to nil
object.oneToOneRelationShip = someOtherObject;

// simply used for debuggin
[object addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"oneToOneRelationShip" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
```

I then post the object using the object manager to post this thing

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:object method:method path:path parameters:parameters];
[objectManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:mainManagedObjectContext success:^{ 
    NSLog(@"blah");
}];
```

Now after this occurs the RestKit starts running operation objects which eventually calls save which works it way to this calls

```
-(void)handleManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
...
    [self.mergeContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
...
```

This is where my KVO observer code signals to me there's a change that was made

```
object.oneToOneRelationShip == nil
```

I believed I fixed my problem by simply saving to the persistent store before I post the object, but can someone please explain to me why this occurred. Am I doing something wrong? This bug was very confusing to me. I create objects off the main context so I don't know how this problem could occur.

Comment: You didn't save your changes before asking RestKit to do work for you? You should... Otherwise a merge rule comes into action and something trumps something else, in this case the update from the background context overwrites the change in the main context.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So a background context overwrites the changes from the main, but  why does that background context have the object with that propery nil'ed? Every other property is properly saved except this one. I've also noticed that saving the context only fixes the problem if I save it right after I created it. When is it the proper time to save the context?

Comment: I'd save before making the request. What is the mapping for that object? And what in the response for the relationship?

Comment: I've tried saving it to the persistent store before I post it but no dice, if I do it right after I create the object I'm okay. I've tried backing up in the timeline from the time I made the request to save the context but I still get the problem. As for the mapping, the "MyObject" has a few attributes and a few relationships all preserved except for that one that gets nil'ed. The relationship is a one to one. While on the flip side the "SomeOtherObject" has a relationship to to "MyObject" that is a one to many type.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear on the question about the response for the relationship question. The response to the HTTP request is a response object, informing me of the server response. Nothing fancy just a NSObject with some strings for the status, server exceptions, messages, etc.

Comment: 2 relationships? It's on to one or one to many, 1 relationship can't be both. It sounds unrelated to merge, rather to relationship combination, or rather overwrite and disconnection, but it's hard to tell without seeing the model and data.

Comment: MyObject can have one SomeOtherObject, but SomeOtherObject can have many MyObject's. Let me extract this problem out into a simplified test project.

Comment: http://imgur.com/WExobk5 Here's a look into my model file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89334/discussion-between-biclops-and-wain).